# Why is my C++ code for an orbit propagator wrong?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, trajectory

I tried making an orbit propagator C++ code.  Its values seem to be propagating evenly but still I get a straight line orbit instead of an elliptical one.  Why?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
ofstream pos("position.txt");
 
typedef struct{
    float i,j,k;
    }Vector;
 
double dotProduct(Vector a, Vector b)
{
    return a.i*b.i+a.j*b.j+a.k*b.k;
}
 
Vector crossProduct(Vector a,Vector b)
{
    Vector c = {a.j*b.k - a.k*b.j, a.k*b.i - a.i*b.k, a.i*b.j - a.j*b.i};
 
    return c;
}

Vector scalerMultiplication(double d,Vector a)
{
    Vector c ={a.i*d,a.j*d,a.k*d};

    return c;
}

Vector scalerDivision(double d,Vector a)
{
    Vector c ={a.i/d,a.j/d,a.k/d};

    return c;
}

Vector Subtraction(Vector a,Vector b)
{
    Vector c = {a.i - b.i, a.j - b.j, a.k - b.k};
 
    return c;
}

double scalarTripleProduct(Vector a,Vector b,Vector c)
{
    return dotProduct(a,crossProduct(b,c));
}
 
Vector vectorTripleProduct(Vector a,Vector b,Vector c)
{
    return crossProduct(a,crossProduct(b,c));
}
 
void printVector(Vector a)
{
    printf("( %f, %f, %f)",a.i,a.j,a.k);
}

float f(double x,double E) { 
    return x-E*sin(x);
}

float derivative(double x,double E) { 
    return 1-E*cos(x);
}

int main()
{
    Vector h,n,p,e;
    double ii,L,O,P;
    Vector r={-5236.84,4124.117,-1262.94};
    Vector v={-3.8628,-3.12848,5.83839};
    Vector I={1,0,0};
    Vector J={0,1,0};
    Vector K={0,0,1};
    double M=3.986004418*pow(10,5);
    h=crossProduct(r,v);
    n=crossProduct(K,h);
    double R=sqrt(dotProduct(r,r));
    double V=sqrt(dotProduct(v,v));
    double H=sqrt(dotProduct(h,h));
    double N=sqrt(dotProduct(n,n));
    e=scalerDivision(M,Subtraction(scalerMultiplication((V*V-M/R),r),scalerMultiplication(dotProduct(r,v),v)));
    double E=V*V/2-M/R;
    double a=-M/(2*E);
    double E1=sqrt(dotProduct(e,e));
    double hK=dotProduct(h,K);
    double nI=dotProduct(n,I);
    double rK=dotProduct(r,K);
    ii=acos(hK/H);
    L=acos(nI/N);
    O=acos(dotProduct(n,e)/(N*E1));
    P=acos(dotProduct(e,r)/(E1*R)); //value of ν
    printf("Value of a is: %lf \n",a); printf("Value of e is: "); printVector(e); printf("\n"); printf("Value of i is: %lf \n",ii); printf("Value of Ω is: %lf \n",L); printf("Value of ω is: %lf \n",O); printf("Value of ν is: %lf \n",P);

    double N1,MA,EA,Y;
    int t;
    for (t=1;t<=6000;t++)
    {
     N1=sqrt(M/pow(a,3));
     double T=(2*3.14/M)*pow(a,1.5);
     MA=N1*(t-T);
     double x; 
     int i = 1, n; 
     x=MA;
     n=4;
     double EA=0;

     while(i <= n) {
         x = x - f(x,E1)/derivative(x,E1);
         EA=EA+x;
         i++;
     }

     double v1=2*atan(sqrt((1+E1)/(1-E1))*tan(EA/2));
     double rr=a*(1-(cos(EA)*E1));
     double pp=rr*(1+E1*cos(v1));
     double hh=sqrt((M*a*(1-E1*E1)));
     double X=((cos(L)*cos(O+v1)-sin(L)*cos(O+v1)*cos(ii))*rr);
     double Y=((sin(L)*cos(O+v1)-cos(L)*cos(O+v1)*cos(ii))*rr);
     double Z=((sin(ii)*sin(O+v1))*rr);
     double X1=(X*hh*E1/(rr*pp)*sin(v1)-hh/rr*(cos(L)*sin(O+v1)+sin(L)*cos(O+v1)*cos(ii)));
     double Y1=(Y*hh*E1/(rr*pp)*sin(v1)-hh/rr*(sin(L)*sin(O+v1)-cos(L)*cos(O+v1)*cos(ii)));
     double Z1=(Z*hh*E1/(rr*pp)*sin(v1)-hh/rr*(sin(ii)*sin(O+v1)));
     
     //printf("Position of Satellite: %lf,%lf,%lf \n",X,Y,Z);
     //printf("Velocity of Satellite: %lf,%lf,%lf \n",X1,Y1,Z1);
     printf("%lf,%lf,%lf \n",X,Y,Z);
     //printf("%lf,%lf,%lf \n",X1,Y1,Z1);
     pos<<X<<" "<<Y<<" "<<Z<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recommend you get out of the habit of using [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077) and [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077). They're bad individually, but especially insidious together.

Comment: Um,  you said C code, but you are using C++ constructs such as `std::ofstream`.

Comment: On a cursory look, it appears that your calculation for Eccentric Anomaly is incorrect, because your `f`` function is incorrect (You need to subtract the Mean Anomaly value ),  otherwise. your use of Newton's Method to find Eccentric Anomaly is _always_ going to converge to Eccentric Anomaly = 0.

Comment: There are many, many things wrong with this code. I suggest you submit this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for review and then come back here regarding the math and physics.

Comment: Do not submit your code to Code Review SE. All you would possibly find out is whether or not your variables and functions have descriptive names or not, if your indentations are nice and clean or not, whether or not your while loops should be replaced with for loops, etc. In worst scenario, it would just result in completely unhelpful nitpicking fest of people jumping to scold you for using namespace std and having commented out `printf` statements. What you need is someone familiar with what the code is supposed to do, and Space Exploration SE is the right place to ask.

Comment: @FredLarson Removing the `using namespace std` line is not going to fix the algorithmic bug that question's author is asking about. Please consider saving such unsolicited and irrelevant advice exclusively for sites which are explicitly about programming, like Code Review or Stack Overflow. I am 100% sure the OP is going to be the only single user of his code, therefore there is no need to pretend this is going to be some module for a commercial 10-million-LOC project somewhere and no need to impose overly strict "standards".

Comment: A link to the formulas you're trying to follow would also be helpful; puzzling out which orbital quantities you've used what variables for is slow going.

Comment: And yeah, your Newton's method loop is _definitely_ broken.  The only reason you're seeing _any_ movement in Eccentric Anomaly from 0 at all is because you're only doing 4 iteration steps, and choosing incrementally worse initial guesses for its attempted calculation of "What is the Eccentric Anomaly when the Mean Anomaly = 0"

Comment: @user47149 I disagree with your recommendations. This code needs to be nitpicked, and Code Review SE is a good place for such nitpicking. It's hard to untangle what's going wrong here because the code is not very good. (And that's being nice.) Regarding `using namespace std` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`: These *are* insidious. The primary reason to learn C++ is to get a job that requires knowledge of C++. If one is doing something aerospace-y for funsies, use python instead. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) It's hard to chase down what's going wrong here because of the poor code quality and complete lack of comments. @notovny chased through some of the algorithmic issues, but apparently not enough so as to write up an answer.

Comment: @user47149 I think the discussion that followed is helpful so I'm going to leave it up, but I want to give you a heads up that phrases like "nitpicking fest of people jumping to scold you" and "there is no need to pretend" are charged language and unfriendly. Avoid using charged language like this, as it is an obstacle to healthy communication. Future comments of this sort will be removed. "Please consider saving such unsolicited and irrelevant advice" also comes across very passive-aggressive.

Comment: @DavidHammen I think you are technically correct, but unless you exactly point out the bugs that using `namespace std` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` supposedly cause in this specific case, then such observations of this code's most superficial qualities are not really going to be helpful to the question's author. It is pure guesswork of people giving their shots about what might be wrong, or just people stating that a lot of things are wrong without specifying said things. If a person with broken {continues}

Comment: @DavidHammen leg visits emergency department, one could be correct by observing that this person for example looks feverish, malnourished, or has bloodshot eyes. It may, or may not be related to the broken leg itself. However, how would such observation be helpful to the person in the context of his/her broken leg? What that person needs to fix the issue is an X-ray shot and orthopedic cast, not random guesses about things that are immediately visible. Just my two cents. Cheers.

Comment: @called2voyage My apologies, I did not intend my comments to be perceived like that. I sort of jumped in to "defend" the question's author because, in my opinion, comments pointing out how the OP uses `namespace std` and `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` are dismissive and unhelpful. Unlike providing actual help by debugging and pointing out the exact culprit of the algorithmic error causing the wrong calculation results OP asks about, making such drive-by observations does not require any time and effort spent on analyzing the code, besides a brief glance. But looking {continues}

Comment: @called2voyage at the comments in this thread, I guess I am in the wrong there. I will do my best to be more friendly and communicative. Cheers.

Comment: I think this question is off Topic

Answer (score 7):

As David Hammen said, there's a *lot* wrong here. I'm not a professional, I'm just a hobbyist who blundered my way through Wikipedia's orbital equations because Kerbal Space program didn't have a map screen back when I started playing it. But here's some of the things I can see that are probably issues.

So, running your code through the [online C++ Compiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HhMZTfo9qPh) produces this:

```
Value of a is: 6789.323783 
Value of e is: ( -0.001016, 0.000074, 0.000551)
Value of i is: 0.900565 
Value of Ω is: 2.625255 
Value of ω is: 0.652596 
Value of ν is: 0.892428 
-6337.843437,5570.515193,3227.223413 
-6337.843440,5570.515195,3227.223411 
-6337.843440,5570.515195,3227.223411 
-6337.843437,5570.515193,3227.223413 
-6337.843437,5570.515193,3227.223413 
-6337.843437,5570.515193,3227.223413
```

Assuming that these are your initial radial distance vector and initial Velocity vector

```
    Vector r={-5236.84,4124.117,-1262.94};
    Vector v={-3.8628,-3.12848,5.83839};
```

And this is your standard gravitational parameter:

```
    double M=3.986004418*pow(10,5);
```

The first issue that *really* jumps out is that your printout of positions doesn't start at the initial position of the object. So, yeah, there's something very wrong here. Probably multiple things.

**Mean Anomaly At Epoch calculation: Nonexistent**

You are completely missing your calculation for Mean Anomaly At Epoch.  This will cause problems with positioning on the orbit. You should calculate Eccentric Anomaly at Epoch from True Anomaly at Epoch,  and calculate Mean Anomaly at Epoch from there. (Unfortunately, I don't have the time to work through this right now, may come back later for this).

Mean Anomaly: You are calculating this backwards for increasing t for some reason. If `M0` was the Mean Anomaly at Epoch that you should have calculated previously, and the epoch is 0, then it would be:

```
MA= M0 + N1*(t);
```

**Eccentric Anomaly Calculation: A significant problem, probably the biggest one.**

As I mentioned in the comments, you appear to be calculating your eccentric anomaly incorrectly in your Newton's Method loop here:

```
     int i = 1, n; 
     x=MA;
     n=4;
     double EA=0;

     while(i <= n) {
         x = x - f(x,E1)/derivative(x,E1);
         EA=EA+x;
         i++;
     }
```

With the below functions

```
float f(double x,double E) { 
    return x-E*sin(x);
}

float derivative(double x,double E) { 
    return 1-E*cos(x);
}
```

The function `f(double x,double E)` is incorrect. As it is, you are solving the equation (and I'm going to use the notation in the Wikipedia article here:
$$ M = E - e\sin E = 0$$

As a result, your Newton's method loop is solving the question of "What is the Eccentric Anomaly when the Mean Anomaly = 0"  I can give you the answer to that; it's 0. Always. (or $2\pi$ or$4\pi$, etc.). It doesn't matter what you choose as the initial guess, the Newton's method calculation will try to converge to 0 given that function.
The equation you want to solve for is:

$$ E - e\sin E - M = 0$$

The only reason you're getting any movement on Eccentric Anomaly at all is because you're advancing your Mean anomaly correctly by the Mean Motion value, and using that as your initial guess `x`, and you're only doing four iterations. Because you're hardcoded to four iterations, using worse and worse initial guesses for the calculation you're doing, your eccentric anomaly value is pulling further and further away from the zero it's trying to calculate.

I'd replace them in the following manner:

```
float f(double x,double E, double MA) { 
    return x-E*sin(x)-MA;
}
```

```
     double EA=0;
     double old_EA = -999;
     while(i <= 30 && abs(EA - old_EA)>0.0001) {
         x = x - f(x,E1, MA)/derivative(x,E1);
         old_EA = EA;
         EA=EA+x;
         i++;
     }
```

**Other orbital parameters: Some problems, but still not the big one**

*Orbital Inclination* looks good.

*Eccentricity Vector*: Looks good.

*Eccentricity value*: Looks good.

*Argument of Periapsis*: Has the right value but only because your chosen parameters put the eccentricity vector in the half of space where your formula works. Also, **`O` is a *terrible* variable name, and you should use something else to avoid confusion with `0`**. If you're not going for lowercase omega, I'd probably use `w`

```
    w=acos(dotProduct(n,e)/(N*E1));
    if (e.j >= 0){
       w= 2 * M_PI - w;
    }
```

Longitude of the Ascending Node: Has the right value, but again, only because your chosen initial parameters point the node vector in the half of space where your chosen formula works. Replace with

```
    L= acos(nI/N);
    if(n.j <= 0){
        L = 2 * M_PI - L;
    }
```

True Anomaly at epoch: Has the wrong value (should be about `5.391`). You've guessed that the object is ascending to apoapsis, but it's actually descending to periapsis.

```
    P=  acos(dotProduct(e,r)/(E1*R)) ; 
    if(dotProduct(r,v) <= 0){
        P = 2 * M_PI - P;
    }
```

**A second large problem: Your Plane Rotation Trigonometry**

I'm pretty sure there is something *very* wonky with your plane rotation trigonometry calculations that attempt to convert these values into cartesian coordinates. I don't have the time to really hash through them right now (and I'm not sure what `hh` is supposed to be without any comments).

So I'll just leave with an image of what the propagated orbit actually looks like, courtesy of a GeoGebra graph I built for this sort of thing about a year ago.

| [GeoGebra Graph](https://www.geogebra.org/m/z263ejvk) of the Orbit of the OP's Object |
| --- |
| [image: Orbit around the OP's Object] |

The point "A" is the first point produced by the OP's code.

Comment: Great analysis!

Comment: Very nice! I couldn't force myself to analyze this code.

Comment: Regarding the single character variable names, `omega` is much better than `o`. Strictly speaking, `omega` is still a single character, just spelled out. Somewhat sarcastically, when I see a newbie programmer use `i`, `j`, and `k` as variable names, I recommend they use  more meaningful names such as `ii`, `jj`, and `kk` instead. Non-sarcastically, there are very few words in the English language that have a double i, double j, or double k. Searching for `ii`, `jj`, or `kk` will inevitably narrow in on the uses of those index variables. Searching for `i`: Good luck!